# Python: Compare 2 strings and see if they contain the same letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

This seems pretty straight-forward but I'm stuck. What I want is to see if a string (str1) contains all the letters that are in a second string (str2). If str1 contains all the letters (in any order, any number of times) then return True. If not, return false.

[Note] Str2 does not necessarily have to have all the letters that str1 has.

Comment: You need to show us your sample input and what you have tried already!

Comment: looks like set() may be a good option here. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: Well, the strings are inputs from the user function(str,str), and then hypothetically one would just compare those strings somehow. I'm really just not sure where to go at all because I tried if...else statements and while statements and just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [malonge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3308509/malonge) mentioned, set() is a good idea for such sort of comparison:

```
a = "abcdefg"
b ="dgggg"

if set(b) & set(a) == set(b) :
    print "foo"
else:
    print "bar"
```

Comment: This should even be simpler: if set(b) - set(a): print "b contains characters different from a"

Comment: Agreed but issubset would be the most pythonic way though

Answer (score 5):

Convert the strings to `set` objects.

`set(str1).issubset(set(str2))`

You can also use this alternative syntax:

`set(str1) <= set(str2)`